# Question on proof of disintegration of measures

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

> In a probabilistic setting: Let $\mu$ be a measure on the product space $S=S_1\times S_2$, both standard Borel,  $\mu_1, \mu_2$ the marginal measures. Then there exists a Markov kernel $k$ such that $\mathrm{d}\mu(x_1,x_2)=k(x_1,\mathrm{d} x_2)\mathrm{d}\mu_1(x_1)$ i.e. $\int_S f\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_{S_1}(\int_{S_2}f(x_1,x_2)k(x_1,\mathrm{d} x_2))\mathrm{d}\mu_1(x_1)$ for measurable $f$.

All the proofs I have seen use the fact that, since we have standard Borel spaces, we can write $\mu_2(x_2 | x_1)$ as a Markov kernel. This is all fine to me. The problem I have is justifying why we can write the product measure as a combination of a conditional measure and the marginal. Intuitively this is clear, we are essentially "slicing" with respect to one space and summing it up. I haven't been able to verify this formally though. Any help is appreciated!